# Running total SQL server - AGAIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm aware that this question has been asked multiple times and I have read those threads to get to where I am now, but those solutions don't seem to be working. I need to have a running total of my ExpectedAmount...

I have the following table:

```
+--------------+----------------+
| ExpectedDate | ExpectedAmount |
+--------------+----------------+
|            1 |        2485513 |
|            2 |         526032 |
|            3 |         342041 |
|            4 |         195807 |
|            5 |         380477 |
|            6 |         102233 |
|            7 |         539951 |
|            8 |         107145 |
|           10 |         165110 |
|           11 |          18795 |
|           12 |          27177 |
|           13 |          28232 |
|           14 |         154631 |
|           15 |        5566585 |
|           16 |         250814 |
|           17 |          90444 |
|           18 |         105424 |
|           19 |          62132 |
|           20 |        1799349 |
|           21 |         303131 |
|           22 |         459464 |
|           23 |         723488 |
|           24 |         676514 |
|           25 |       17311911 |
|           26 |        4876062 |
|           27 |        4844434 |
|           28 |        4039687 |
|           29 |        1418648 |
|           30 |        4366189 |
|           31 |        9028836 |
+--------------+----------------+
```

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT a.ExpectedDate, a.ExpectedAmount, (SELECT SUM(b.ExpectedAmount)
                       FROM UnpaidManagement..Expected b
                       WHERE b.ExpectedDate <= a.ExpectedDate)
FROM   UnpaidManagement..Expected a
```

The result of the above SQL is this:

```
+--------------+----------------+--------------+
| ExpectedDate | ExpectedAmount | RunningTotal |
+--------------+----------------+--------------+
|            1 |        2485513 |      2485513 |
|            2 |         526032 |      9480889 |
|            3 |         342041 |     46275618 |
|            4 |         195807 |     59866450 |
|            5 |         380477 |     60246927 |
|            6 |         102233 |     60349160 |
|            7 |         539951 |     60889111 |
|            8 |         107145 |     60996256 |
|           10 |         165110 |      2650623 |
|           11 |          18795 |      2669418 |
|           12 |          27177 |      2696595 |
|           13 |          28232 |      2724827 |
|           14 |         154631 |      2879458 |
|           15 |        5566585 |      8446043 |
|           16 |         250814 |      8696857 |
|           17 |          90444 |      8787301 |
|           18 |         105424 |      8892725 |
|           19 |          62132 |      8954857 |
|           20 |        1799349 |     11280238 |
|           21 |         303131 |     11583369 |
|           22 |         459464 |     12042833 |
|           23 |         723488 |     12766321 |
|           24 |         676514 |     13442835 |
|           25 |       17311911 |     30754746 |
|           26 |        4876062 |     35630808 |
|           27 |        4844434 |     40475242 |
|           28 |        4039687 |     44514929 |
|           29 |        1418648 |     45933577 |
|           30 |        4366189 |     50641807 |
|           31 |        9028836 |     59670643 |
+--------------+----------------+--------------+
```

You can tell from the first few values already that the math is all off, but then at some points the math adds up?! I'm Too confused !! Could someone please point me to another solution or to where I have gone wrong with this?

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because your ExpectedDate column of type varchar. Try this:

```
SELECT a.ExpectedDate, a.ExpectedAmount, (SELECT SUM(b.ExpectedAmount)
                       FROM UnpaidManagement..Expected b
                       WHERE CAST(b.ExpectedDate as int) <= CAST(a.ExpectedDate as int))
FROM   UnpaidManagement..Expected a
```

Note that it could be inefficient query.

Comment: Aww you CHAMP!! it was indeed VARCHAR, yikes!! Thanks so much... This sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this gonna work:

```
SELECT a.ExpectedDate, 
       a.ExpectedAmount,
       SUM(b.ExpectedAmount) RuningTotal
FROM   UnpaidManagement..Expected a
LEFT JOIN UnpaidManagement..Expected b
  ON CAST(b.ExpectedDate as int) <= CAST(a.ExpectedDate as int)
GROUP BY a.ExpectedDate, a.ExpectedAmount
```

AND:

```
SELECT a.ExpectedDate, 
       a.ExpectedAmount,
       c.RuningTotal
FROM   UnpaidManagement..Expected a
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT SUM(b.ExpectedAmount) AS RuningTotal
  FROM UnpaidManagement..Expected b
  WHERE  CAST(b.ExpectedDate as int) <= CAST(a.ExpectedDate as int)
  ) c
```